# Php mysql count row using groupby not working?

Tags: php, mysql

Php mysql count row using groupby not working ?

Table : test_table

```
__________________________
| id | name |    note    |
| 1  | aaa  |  234234234 |
| 2  | aaa  |  kjhkjhkjj |
| 3  | bbb  |  jhghjgjjj |
| 4  | bbb  |  uiyiuyutt |
```

..............

```
<?PHP
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `test_table` GROUP BY name");
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        mysql_free_result($result);
        $row_result = $row[0];
        echo $row_result;
?>
```

When i tested this code it's echo `1`

I want to get result `2` How can i do ?

Comment: What are you trying to count?

Comment: mysql_ functions depricated since PHP 7 and using from that create issue for you.
Also COUNT(*) make to much resources from you, it is better to use COUNT(id)

Comment: @MajidAbbasi with respect, the opposite is true. `COUNT(*)` is substantially faster than `COUNT(id)`.  Why? Because the query planner only needs to know the number of rows, not anything about their contents, to satisfy `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 2):

You should loop result:

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT name, COUNT(id) cnt FROM `test_table` GROUP BY name");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['name'].' : '.$row['cnt'];
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
```

And for sure you should stop using `mysql_` functions they are deprecated for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

> `mysql` is deprected no longer use,use `mysqli` or `pdo`

```
 <?PHP
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(name) FROM `test_table` GROUP BY name");
if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $row_result = $row[0];
        echo $row_result;
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
}
?>
```

Comment: Uhhh, the code still needs to read all the rows of the result set, not just the first.

Comment: above code return count for name.if same name is more than  one than it returns count of that name